# undefined method `order_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000000bd1aac8>:0x000000000bd18408>

Tags: html, sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I keep getting this error when i want to enter the index page , the weird thing is that when i enter to the new order page it works fine and i been scratching my head with this error for a few days any answer?. In the routes i have listings do routes .

**This is my Orders Controller:**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @seller = @listing.user

    @order.listing_id = @listing.id
    @order.buyer_id = current_user.id
    @order.seller_id = @seller.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Pedido creado' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'El pedido fue actualizado' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'El pedido fue eliminado con exito' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:address, :city, :state)
    end
end
```

**My Index Page:**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Orders</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>State</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= order.address %></td>
        <td><%= order.city %></td>
        <td><%= order.state %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Mostrar', order %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Editar', edit_listing_order_path(order) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Eliminar', order, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Estas seguro?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Order', new_listing_order_path %>
```

**Form:**

```
<%= form_for(model: [@listing, @order], local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :address %>
    <%= form.text_field :address %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :city %>
    <%= form.text_field :city %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :state %>
    <%= form.text_field :state %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

**Routes.rb:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  devise_for :users
  resources :listings do
    resources :orders
```

**Rake routes:**

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern   Controller#Action
                     new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#new
                         user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                 devise/sessions#create
                 destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                devise/sessions#destroy
                    new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                                            devise/passwords#new
                   edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                                           devise/passwords#edit
                        user_password PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                      PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#update
                                      POST   /users/password(.:format)                                                                devise/passwords#create
             cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                                                  devise/registrations#cancel
                new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#new
               edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                                    devise/registrations#edit
                    user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                                      PUT    /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#update
                                      DELETE /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#destroy
                                      POST   /users(.:format)                                                                         devise/registrations#create
                       listing_orders GET    /listings/:listing_id/orders(.:format)                                                   orders#index
                                      POST   /listings/:listing_id/orders(.:format)                                                   orders#create
                    new_listing_order GET    /listings/:listing_id/orders/new(.:format)                                               orders#new
                   edit_listing_order GET    /listings/:listing_id/orders/:id/edit(.:format)                                          orders#edit
                        listing_order GET    /listings/:listing_id/orders/:id(.:format)                                               orders#show
                                      PATCH  /listings/:listing_id/orders/:id(.:format)                                               orders#update
                                      PUT    /listings/:listing_id/orders/:id(.:format)                                               orders#update
                                      DELETE /listings/:listing_id/orders/:id(.:format)                                               orders#destroy
                             listings GET    /listings(.:format)                                                                      listings#index
                                      POST   /listings(.:format)                                                                      listings#create
                          new_listing GET    /listings/new(.:format)                                                                  listings#new
                         edit_listing GET    /listings/:id/edit(.:format)                                                             listings#edit
                              listing GET    /listings/:id(.:format)                                                                  listings#show
                                      PATCH  /listings/:id(.:format)                                                                  listings#update
                                      PUT    /listings/:id(.:format)                                                                  listings#update
                                      DELETE /listings/:id(.:format)                                                                  listings#destroy
                          pages_about GET    /pages/about(.:format)                                                                   pages#about
                        pages_contact GET    /pages/contact(.:format)                                                                 pages#contact
                               seller GET    /seller(.:format)                                                                        listings#seller
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        listings#index
        rails_postmark_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/postmark/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/postmark/inbound_emails#create
           rails_relay_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/relay/inbound_emails(.:format)                                     action_mailbox/ingresses/relay/inbound_emails#create
        rails_sendgrid_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/sendgrid/inbound_emails#create
  rails_mandrill_inbound_health_check GET    /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#health_check
        rails_mandrill_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mandrill/inbound_emails(.:format)                                  action_mailbox/ingresses/mandrill/inbound_emails#create
         rails_mailgun_inbound_emails POST   /rails/action_mailbox/mailgun/inbound_emails/mime(.:format)                              action_mailbox/ingresses/mailgun/inbound_emails#create
       rails_conductor_inbound_emails GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#index
                                      POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails(.:format)                                 rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#create
    new_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/new(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#new
   edit_rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id/edit(.:format)                        rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#edit
        rails_conductor_inbound_email GET    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#show
                                      PATCH  /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      PUT    /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#update
                                      DELETE /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails/:id(.:format)                             rails/conductor/action_mailbox/inbound_emails#destroy
rails_conductor_inbound_email_reroute POST   /rails/conductor/action_mailbox/:inbound_email_id/reroute(.:format)                      rails/conductor/action_mailbox/reroutes#create
                   rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
            rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
                   rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
            update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
                 rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Comment: It the path `listing_order` or `order`?  I noticed your edit method has `edit_listing_order_path`.  Right now your code looks like it will create `order_path` in the `show` and `delete` options in the index view.Does it work if you change the show and delete methods in the index view to be `listing_order_path(order)` ?

Comment: I did that a few days ago but it gave me this error: "No route matches {: action =>" show ",: controller =>" orders ",: listing_id => #" and yes my routes are listing_order

Comment: Ya you have a naming issue here.  You didn't include it in your code,  what is this orders controller actually called, can you post your whole routes file also?

Comment: In "ADDITIONAL INFO" I put all the routes and the name appears as "Orders_Controller"

Comment: One of the problems you have is your orders are nested under your listings which means every action in your orders controller also needs a listing. I don't see that happening right now. Maybe put the listing in a before_action, like this: `before_action :set_listing`. Then create a `set_listing` method that looks up the listing: `def set_listing @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id]) end`. Also, are you accessing the orders index view like this: `localhost:3000/listings/1/orders`?

Comment: Yeah thats exactly how i access orders index. I did what you suggest and the error keeps popping. Sorry for being so dumb im starting on rails .